# Why would Doctor Strange Become 'The Sorcerer Supreme'?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, doctor-strange, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In a piece of the script from *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, it explains how Wong becomes Sorcerer Supreme, since Doctor Strange blipped. However, I don't think it is explained why Doctor Strange would have become Sorcerer Supreme after The Ancient One dies; he was only a student for (around) a year, when other sorcerers like Wong and Mordo have been sorcerers for (perhaps?) years...

> **DR. STRANGE**:
> “Higher duties?!”
>
> **WONG**:
> The Sorcerer Supreme has higher duties, yes.
>
> **PETER** *(to Dr. Strange)*:
> Wait, I thought you were the Sorcerer Supreme--
>
> **DR. STRANGE**:
> No, he got it on a technicality ‘cause I blipped for five years.
>
> **PETER**:
> Oh.
> *(to Wong)*
> Well, congratulations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Stephen Strange was never named (in the MCU) as the Sorceror Supreme

It's clear that he *might* have been awarded the title (the Ancient One suggested that Strange was "the best of us") but due to the Blip, this title went to Wong.

Frankly, it seems to a title without much benefit since Strange can do anything Wong can do (it seems) and ignores Wong's instructions whenever he feels like it.

Comment: The Ancient One’s voiceover in _What If Doctor Strange Lost His Heart Instead of His Hands_ suggest that he became Sorcerer Supreme in that universe, in relatively similar circumstances to the MCU.

Comment: He is the sorcerer supreme from 2016-2018...